# What are the pros and cons of using Joomla as a CMS for an e-commerce site selling physical products?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, e-commerce

> I am not a developer/engineer so
>   please excuse my ignorance (and feel
>   free to edit where I have not
>   expressed myself correctly)

In particular I would like to know if Joomla is sufficiently complex to handle:

1. Using the API of several logistics/delivery services
2. Doing A/B testing
3. Integrating seemlesly with a payment gateway
4. Any other important things I am not even thinking about just yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want to know about Joomla, you want to know about the e-commerce extensions for Joomla. If you are purely going to be selling products and not producing any content, then I would probably opt for a dedicated e-commerce solution like Magento. If you need the additional features for managing content outside of the products you intend to sell then I would go with Joomla + Virtuemart + k2 + K2mart. Joomla and K2 will handle all of the content needs you may have. Virtuemart is the most robust of the e-commerce packages but it can be hard to work with for product display, which is why I recommend K2mart. This allows you to use the checkout portion of VM - payment processing, shipping calculations, invoices and notification with the power of K2 templating to display product categories and detail pages. It also makes your e-commerce pages much more SEO friendly. All of those are free extensions with the exception of K2mart which is very reasonably priced.

Virtuemart has a large selection of shipping options including several popular shipping services with APIs. They have payment processing for all of the big paymeny gateways. You can do A/B testing with an extension designed to integrate with Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me also if there are any disadvantaeges or limitations to using Joomla - some things we should have in mind if and when we expand?

Comment: The main disadvantage of not using a dedicated e-commerce system is that there are less features and options. That's not to say that they can't be added. They're all just PHP code and anything that you can do in one can be ported to the other. Dedicated e-comm will usually have more payment options, more shipping options, better reporting, more coupon/gift certificate options. Things of that nature.